# Why sequelize insert twice?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, fastify

I try to insert a data into databased, but when de endpoint was called, the data was inserted twice.

I try to use async await, call model outside the function, use promise, and the problem not resolved.

Insert:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  let User = require('./models').User;

  User.create({
    id: 0,
    name: 'Jon',
    age: 21,
    email: 'test@gameil.com',
    city: 1
  })
  .then(result => {
    res.send(result);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  })
}
```

Model index:

```
'use strict';

const fs        = require('fs');
const path      = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename  = path.basename(__filename);

//PRINCIPAL DATABASE CONFIG
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'main';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../../configs/v1/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');//open .js file
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));//connect data base using file model
    db[model.name] = model;//model.name example (const model = require(./model).modelName;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
```

Model:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    let Users= sequelize.define('Users', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        age:{
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false
        },
        email:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
            allowNull: false
        },
        city:{
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false
        },
  }, {
    tableName: 'users',
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true
  });
  Users.associate = function (models) {
        Users.belongsTo(models.Cities, { foreignKey: 'city' });
  }
  return Users;
};
```

Route:

```
const controller = require('../controllers/userController');

module.exports = (router, opts, done)=>{
    router.post('/', controller.create);
    done();
}
```

app:

```
const users = require('./routes/users');

app.register(users, { prefix: '/user' });
```

I need that query insert just one data, not twice, any idea to resolve?

Comment: Code is fine, please check you might be calling the api/function twice.

Comment: Please show the endpoint code

Comment: I call one time, and into test, when i just dont cal .create the function execute one time, but when User.create there, the function execute twice, but i dont know why.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek i edited post, and put router and app code that.

Comment: Weird, have you tried debugging with `console.log()`? Is the `controller.create` method called twice?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek i try, and when user.create was called, the console.log that into function create, execute twice, but when i had commented User.create, the console.log execute one time

Comment: the model exposes a function but you are using a property `let User = require('./models').User;`. could you add all the code?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon i have an index into model that call sequelize connection, but i try  make the isertion without that and a raw query like that:

let sequelize = new sequelize(configs);
sequelize.query('INSERT INTO....').then(result => {res.send(result)});

And the query execute twice again

Comment: If you define your fastify server with `logger: {level:'debug'}` you see a log foreach request so if you see 2 calls when you expect one, the problem is on the client you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the:

```
addHook('prehandler', async(req, res, done)=>{
  done();//its wrong because use async/await
});
```

Correct:

```
addHook('prehandler', async(req, res)=>{
  return
});
```

The done callback is not available when using async/await or returning a Promise. If you do invoke a done callback in this situation unexpected behavior may occur, e.g. duplicate invocation of handlers.